# WIndow.onload() not working on IE to hide table rows

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
     cells = document.getElementsByName('assetID');
     for(j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) cells[j].style.display = 'none';
     cellsBMPartNo = document.getElementsByName('BMPartNo');
     for(j = 0; j < cellsBMPartNo.length; j++) cellsBMPartNo[j].style.display = 'none';
     defaultAssetTableValues();
}
```

I am simply hiding table rows by name. 
See line 2 and 4 . 
It works fine in Firefox but does not in IE. 
Am I missing something ?

Comment: Not using braces for the body of your `for` loop can lead to very misleading code.  Perhaps not what's causing your problem here, but not a good style to follow.

Comment: Also, don't forget to declare your local variables ("cells", "j", "cellsBMPartNo") with the `var` keyword!

Comment: THanks thats a useful tip.. Actually I do follow it this one was simply copy pasted from a link I found. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE does not see elements added to the document dynamically (through the DOM) with `getElementsByName`. Are your elements created that way?

There are other problems with that method in different versions of IE. As a workaround, you could use `getElementsByTagName('td')` and then check to see if the `name` attribute matches the one you are looking for in a for-loop, iterating through the array of elements.

Here's a "IE-fixed" version of `getElementsByName`:

```
function getElementsByName2(tag, name) {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        if (els[i].getAttribute("name") == name) {
            arr.push(els[i]);
        }   
    }
    return arr;
}
```

And you would use it like so (for elements in table cells with name 'assetID'):

```
var cells = getElementsByName2('td', 'assetID');
```

Comment: Worked just for future reference     for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) there was a small error in the for loop. But over all it worked. thanks

Comment: Marking this answer as yes as I cannot use class name as table is already set using name.

Comment: This might not work for elements that can legitimately have "name" attributes, like `<input>` tags for example. It might be better to check for a property on each element before checking via ".getAttribute()". (This will fix the problem with the original post, however, because I think it's exactly that problem that IE's built-in "getElementsByName()" doesn't fix.)

Comment: @user1021125: Ahh, yes, those pesky semicolons. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I am having a problem for a select tab. How do I fix that. there are some values I set on a click for a select tag. With your funcion it works in firefox but not in ie. select ofcourse has some option tags in it.

Answer (score 0):

IE could be looking for a `name` with `assetID` is you assetID defined in the name attribute?

as the others pointed out the name attribute is't for TD`s

ive noticed you have undeclared variables, `cells, j, j, cellsBMPartNo` also for one of the `j's` set one of those to `i` for example to make it easer to follow as well

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that `<tr>` and `<td>` elements really don't support a "name" attribute. IE doesn't complain directly, but its "getElementsByName()" function will not pay attention to elements like that.

You might want to use a "class" value instead.